# Need help on mixed models’

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

In the experiment 25 alpine skiers did a pretest (3 runs), two training sessions (5 run each) and a posttest (3 runs), during the training sessions I split skiers in two different groups and they trained with two different methods.

I have two hypothesis where I think one group will outperform the other one.

1. Learning: where I think one group will outperform the other one at POSTTEST
2. Performance: where I think one group will outperform the other one during the two training sessions

My dataset looks like this: (if you need more I can send you)

```
structure(list(BIB. = structure(c(10L, 25L, 22L, 7L, 8L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
"29"), class = "factor"), Gruppe = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), levels = c("EF", "IF"), class = "factor"), Run = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), `Performance Time` = c(3.265, 2.665, 2.295, 2.87, 1.245
), Session = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Pretest", 
"Trening 1", "Trening 2", "Posttest"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have also been making dummy variable (1 if in group, 0 if not) of these;
D_gruppe
Session_Pretest
`Session_Trening 1`
`Session_Trening 2`
Session_Posttest

```
Learning <- lmer(Performance_Time ~ D_gruppe*Session_Pretest*Session_Posttest 
              + (1|BIB.) + (1|Performance_Time), data)




Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error        df t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 1.73745    0.17672  23.20492   9.832 0.00000000096228820 ***
D_gruppe                   -0.28826    0.25404  22.74112  -1.135             0.26833    
Session_Pretest             0.54241    0.06464 333.00002   8.392 0.00000000000000139 ***
Session_Posttest           -0.02623    0.06556 331.96347  -0.400             0.68934    
D_gruppe:Session_Pretest    0.29673    0.09086 315.22625   3.266             0.00121 ** 
D_gruppe:Session_Posttest   0.24381    0.09508 311.20751   2.564             0.01081 *

NB: Fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients
```

```
Performance  <- lmer(Performance_Time ~ D_gruppe*`Session_Trening 1`*`Session_Trening 2` + (1|BIB.)+ (1|Performance_Time), data)


Fixed effects:
                                Estimate Std. Error        df t value        Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                      2.01527    0.17963  23.91889  11.219 0.0000000000518 ***
D_gruppe1                       -0.01327    0.25922  23.83809  -0.051        0.959600    
`Session_Trening 1`1            -0.25319    0.06520 331.15639  -3.883        0.000124 ***
`Session_Trening 2`1            -0.30096    0.06997 308.15178  -4.301 0.0000228229014 ***
D_gruppe1:`Session_Trening 1`1  -0.15125    0.09436 288.25119  -1.603        0.110045    
D_gruppe1:`Session_Trening 2`1  -0.40798    0.09864 284.29362  -4.136 0.0000465465789 ***

NB: Fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients
```

```
Combi  <- lmer(Performance_Time ~ D_gruppe*Session_Pretest*`Session_Trening 1`*`Session_Trening 2`*Session_Posttest
             + (1|BIB.) + (1|Performance_Time), data)


Fixed effects:
                                Estimate Std. Error        df t value          Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                      1.71698    0.18437  26.29124   9.313 0.000000000822521 ***
D_gruppe1                       -0.05889    0.26648  26.37089  -0.221          0.826791    
Session_Pretest1                 0.57474    0.07644 329.70574   7.518 0.000000000000529 ***
`Session_Trening 1`1             0.03276    0.06853 331.09471   0.478          0.632962    
`Session_Trening 2`1            -0.01135    0.07201 324.09671  -0.158          0.874802    
D_gruppe1:Session_Pretest1       0.05871    0.11083 324.39636   0.530          0.596656    
D_gruppe1:`Session_Trening 1`1  -0.09119    0.10106 318.79226  -0.902          0.367565    
D_gruppe1:`Session_Trening 2`1  -0.37456    0.10321 311.02413  -3.629          0.000332 ***



NB: fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 24 columns / coefficients
```

I’m pretty new to mixed models an im not sure If I have been building the right mixed models’ formula? And I if I can answer my two hypothesis with this approach.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question title is very vague, what's your precise problem ? You can check out the stats version of SO : https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I suggest you to split the question in several questions in order to focus the response. This will bring you more and better responses to your topic. Besides, the teorethical interpretation could be relevant in crossvalidated site rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: You should probably leave the categorical variables as factors rather than generating your own dummy variables - R does this in an integrated way that will be less painful in the long run.

Comment: @BenBolker I see, butt this is only if i have 2 Factors like pre and Post  ( O,1) ? It Wont be wrong if it’s like 4 levels?

Comment: No, R will generally do the right thing.

Comment: thank you @BenBolker! So coding a. Dummy like this in chapter 4.5.4.4 Example: Five-level factor ( https://psyteachr.github.io/stat-models-v1/interactions.html?q=Dumm#treatment-dummy ) is not Necessary?

Comment: lmer(Performance_Time ~ Group*Session + (1|BIB.) + (1|Performance_Time), data). Then will this make sense ? Where group had 2 levels and session has 4 ? @BenBolker

Comment: the contrasts there are available either in base R, see http://faculty.nps.edu/sebuttre/home/r/contrasts.html . The `faux` package may also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker! Will check out! The output  was pretty much the same with normal factors from R